# How to properly use tox to test

Tags: pyenv, tox

Following my last question, I have installed pyenv in order to use tox

I have the following

```
pyenv versions
  system
  3.9.16
  3.9.16/envs/myproject
  3.9.16/envs/project1
  3.10.1
* myproject (set by /home/me/borrar/project3/.python-version)
  project1
```

I have installed tox.

My tox.ini file is

```
# content of: tox.ini , put in same dir as setup.py
[tox]
envlist = py39,py310

[testenv]
# install pytest in the virtualenv where commands will be executed
deps = pytest
commands =
    # NOTE: you can run any command line tool here - not just tests
    pytest
```

When I run tox (from myproject) I get

```
tox
py39: commands[0]> pytest
========================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.16, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
cachedir: .tox/py39/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/me/borrar/project3
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                         

test_sum.py .                                                                                                                                                      [100%]

=========================================================================== 1 passed in 0.01s ============================================================================
py39: OK ✔ in 0.22 seconds
py310: skipped because could not find python interpreter with spec(s): py310
  py39: OK (0.22=setup[0.03]+cmd[0.19] seconds)
  py310: SKIP (0.20 seconds)
  congratulations :) (0.47 seconds)
```

So what am I doing wrong? I thought that once py310 is installed in some pyenv environment it would work

Unfortunately the tox tutorials all assume that the python versions are already installed so no explanation on how to do it correctly from scratch

Can I get the correct flow of how can I do this in order for tox to work on several environments?

Answer (score 2):

`tox` must be able to find the executable for the different python versions. So it must be able to run `python3.9`, `python3.10` and so on.

Usually installing multiple python versions via `pyenv` isn't sufficient. They must be activated as well.

I'd recommend, once you've install a python version, make it available globally. You can have multiple versions activated at the same time. E.g.

```
pyenv global system 3.9.16 3.10.1
```

`pyenv versions` should now show a `*` for each activated version and `tox` will be able to find the interpreter.